# iOS animation works perfect on iOS version 11.0 and above but the something is going wrong on iOS version below 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints

Here, I attached code created by me to do animations,

```
class GIFView: UIView  {

    @IBOutlet  var firstViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet  var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet  var firstView: UIView!

    var objLabel:LabelView?

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }

    func gifDemo(name:String) {
        let animation = LOTAnimationView(name: name)
        secondView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animation.frame.size.width = secondView.frame.size.width
        animation.frame.size.height = secondView.frame.size.height
        secondView.addSubview(animation)
        animation.play()
    }

    func preparelbl(name:String,points:String){
        registerXIB()
        objLabel?.prepareLabels(name: name, points: points)
    }

    func registerXIB() {
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "LabelView", bundle: nil)
        objLabel = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? LabelView
        objLabel?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: firstView.bounds.size.width , height: firstView.bounds.size.height)
        firstView.addSubview(objLabel!)
    }

    func animation(view:UIView) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {

            self.firstView.alpha = 1.0
            self.secondView.alpha = 0.0


        }) { (isTrue) in
            self.secondView.isHidden = true
            self.animationFirstView(view:view)
        }

    }

    func animationFirstView(view:UIView) {
            self.commonAnimation(duration:0.5,delay:0.0)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
                while self.firstViewHeight.multiplier > 0 {
                     self.animationWithCompletion(duration:0.3,delay:0.0,view:view)

                }
            })
    }

    func commonAnimation(duration:Double,delay:Double){
        UIView.animate(withDuration:duration, delay: delay , options: [], animations: {
             let mult = self.firstViewHeight.multiplier - 0.5
            self.firstViewHeight = self.firstViewHeight.changeMultiplier(multiplier: mult)
            self.firstView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height * mult / 2
            self.firstView.layoutIfNeeded()  
        })
    }

    func animationWithCompletion(duration:Double,delay:Double,view:UIView){
        UIView.animate(withDuration:duration, delay: delay , options: [], animations: {
                 let mult = self.firstViewHeight.multiplier - 0.01
                self.firstViewHeight = self.firstViewHeight.changeMultiplier(multiplier: mult)
                self.firstView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height * mult / 2
                //self.firstView.clipsToBounds = true
                self.firstView.layoutIfNeeded()



        }) { (isTrue) in
            view.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}


public extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    func changeMultiplier(multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self])
        let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: firstItem,
            attribute: firstAttribute,
            relatedBy: relation,
            toItem: secondItem,
            attribute: secondAttribute,
            multiplier: multiplier,
            constant: constant)
        newConstraint.priority = priority

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([newConstraint])
        return newConstraint
    }
}
```

The above code run perfect on iOS version 11.0 and above but something is going wrong on iOS version below 11.0 which i don't understand if anyone know the solution then please give me the suggestion to fix it 
Thank You.

Comment: Ever thought about keyframe animations?  Move the part in animationWithCompletion where you set first view height out of the animation and just before it.

Comment: I'm working on a hunch here but I suspect the issue is with your autolayout animations. In iOS 11 safe areas were introduced and there tends to be a backward compatibility issue with iOS 10 devices and below. If you could be more specific about the problem you see it would be helpful to those who might have an answer for you.